# How to toggle/switch the classes between three or more divs in a sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I easily toggle/switch the classes between three or more divs in a sequence by click?

Example html:

```
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box active">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>

<div class="next">Next</div>
<div class="back">Back</div>
```

This way just works with two:

```
$(".next, .back").click(function(){
  $(".box").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty generic

```js
$(".nav").on("click", function() {
  var dir = $(this).is(".next") ? 1 : -1; // which direction are we going?
  var active = $(".box.active").index() - 1;
  var $boxes = $(".box");
  active += (1 * dir);
  if (active < 0) active = $boxes.length - 1; // wrap
  else if (active >= $boxes.length) active = 0;
  $(".box").removeClass("active");
  $(".box").eq(active).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box active">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
<br/>
<div class="nav back">Back</div>
<div class="nav next">Next</div>
```

Comment: it is not generic because it use the id property of the element, so it force the user to put that id (that should be unique) on an element

Comment: I have changed to use a class. If the thing is wrapped, one can use closest(...).find

Answer (score 3):

Simply to check if nth-child has the active class and loop.

```js
$(".next").click(function(){
    $(".box").each( function(i, j) {
        if( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(".box:nth-child("+(((i+1)%$(".box").length)+1)+")").addClass('active');
            return false;
        }
    });
}); 
$(".back").click(function(){
    $(".box").each( function(i, j) {
        if( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(".box:nth-child("+(((i-1)+$(".box").length)%$(".box").length+1)+")").addClass('active');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div class="box">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box active">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box">Box 3</div>

    <div class="back">Back</div>
    <div class="next">Next</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for help, but this "dirty way" I want to avoid ;), because it will become really fast very big code for more divs aso.

Comment: That is not very generic.

Comment: Made it more generic.

Comment: Thx for the update, but the "back" button will not work at this example, I think?

Comment: DRY: Don't repeat yourself. Also You can create a stacksnippet here at SO by clicking the `[<>]` button in the editor

Comment: Thx for the finale version and your support!

Answer (score 1):

I've created another solution that gets the button's ID (which I've added) and uses that to dictate where to go.

```js
var box = $('.box');
var maxBoxes = box.length;
$("#nextBtn, #backBtn").click(function() {
  var getBtn = $(this).get(0).id,
    activeBox = $('.box.active'),
    position = activeBox.index();
    activeBox.removeClass('active');
  if (getBtn === 'nextBtn') {
    (position == maxBoxes) ? box.eq(0).addClass('active'): activeBox.next().addClass('active');
  } else {
    (position === 1) ? box.last().addClass('active'): activeBox.prev().addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box active">Box 3</div>

<div id="nextBtn" class="next">Next</div>
<div id="backBtn" class="back">Back</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following should be efficient, because it will not do unnecessary checks.

```
var last = $(".active")

function toggle(dir){
  var future = last[dir]();
  if(!(future.length && future.hasClass('box'))) {
    return;
  }
  last.toggleClass("active")
  last = future
  last.toggleClass("active");
}

$(".next").click(toggle.bind(void 0, 'next'));
$(".back").click(toggle.bind(void 0, 'prev'));
```